# itextSharp - cannot resubmit form data after pdf is created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, pdf, itext

I created a pdf form in LiveCycle, saved and reader enabled. I have 2 buttons on the form.  The first button hits a webservice to populate a dropdown list n the form, and the other button is a submit, which submits the XML data to an MVC Controller method and puts the xml data in a sql database.  There is another MVC Controller method the uses itextsharp to open the LiveCycle pdf and fill it with the xml data from SQL.  My problem is that the form, after it uses the itextSharp stuff to do its thing, need to be able to resubmit any changes to the form using the submit button.  2 things are happening, and I am not Flattening the form.  1) The button that hits the webservice to populate the dropdownlist does not show unless I scroll out of view and back in. But even then, the dropdownlist shows what was chosen, but cannot be repopulated. Like the button doesn't work or something.  2) The submit button will not work either.  I can click, but it does nothing. Any help is appreciated. My code that uses itextsharp is below.

```
public void PDFBuilder(int FormID)
    {
        int id = 0;
        id = FormID;// Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        var oRow = db.SubmissionsGenerals.Find(id);
        string fv = db.FormVersions.Where(w => w.GUID == oRow.FormGUID).Select(s => s.FormPathFillable).First();
        string xML = string.Empty;
        xML = oRow.XMLData.ToString();
        XmlDocument oXmlData = new XmlDocument();
        oXmlData.LoadXml(xML);
        string m_FormsPath = "http://myformsurl" + fv.TrimStart('.');
        fv = fv.TrimStart('.');
        if (fv != null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = GeneratePDF(m_FormsPath, oXmlData);
            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.End();
        }
    }

    public MemoryStream GeneratePDF(string m_FormName, XmlDocument oData)
    {

        PdfReader pdfTemplate;
        PdfStamper stamper;
        PdfReader tempPDF;
        Document doc;
        MemoryStream msTemp;
        PdfWriter pCopy;

        MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();

        pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(m_FormName);

        doc = new Document();
        pCopy = new PdfCopy(doc, msOutput);
        pCopy.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.PICKTRAYBYPDFSIZE, new PdfBoolean(true));
        pCopy.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.PRINTSCALING, PdfName.NONE);

        doc.Open();

        for(int i=1; i<pdfTemplate.NumberOfPages + 1; i++)
        {
            msTemp = new MemoryStream();
            pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(m_FormName);
            stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, msTemp);

            foreach(XmlElement oElem in oData.SelectNodes("/form1/*"))
            {

                stamper.AcroFields.SetField(oElem.Name, oElem.InnerText);
            }

            //stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            stamper.Close();
            tempPDF = new PdfReader(msTemp.ToArray());
            ((PdfCopy)pCopy).AddPage(pCopy.GetImportedPage(tempPDF, i));

            pCopy.FreeReader(tempPDF);
        }
        doc.Close();
        return msOutput;
    }
```

Comment: You merge the pages of multiple documents in `GeneratePDF`. This process can be destructive to document level data (after all, the *pages* are merged), e.g. XFA forms or document level JavaScript. Do you have any of these in your PDF?

Comment: I do not have any XFA or javascript in the form

Comment: In that case please supply the PDF in question.